# Why is TestNG Randomly Executing my Tests in parrallel?

Tags: testng, pom.xml

Why is `TestNG` randomly executing my tests in parrallel?

1. This issue has randomly happened before, all of a sudden my test would execute at the same time, for example: 
   `TestA` should execute and finish, then `TestB`
2. Suddenly both tests are executing at the same time
3. Any ideas why this happens randomely, this is not an issue with the TestNG file
   [image]

Comment: iv tried thread.count of 1 etc

Comment: how do you invoke those tests? using maven?

Comment: If you are not able to reproduce the issue easily, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski i invoke the tests using TestNG.xml executor file

Comment: How about that `RetryListener` could it be it runs TestA again?

Comment: @Moshisho i have tried to remove the listener and it still fails, its every weird i dont understand why TestNG would try to execute both tests at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by POM.xml

Clean the project before executing new tests. Think of it is clearing up the cache memory.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the POM.xml file and then adding the same POM.xml file seemed to ressolve my issue